# Check if string contains specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

```
my_string = "wolfofwalstreet(2012)is a movie"
```

Need to run python script to check if it contain the character: **bracket**

> "("

Comment: Please format your code block, add your attempts you did so and what error message you received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will give you the index of the character been found.

```
my_string = "wolfofwalstreet(2012)is a movie"

result = my_string.find('(')
print("Found", result)
```

If the character is not found, you receive an  '**-1**'.

As described by the answers below, you can of course but it in an IF-statement.

Answer (score 10):

hi you can check by this way:

```
my_string = "wolfofwalstreet(2012)is a movie"
if '(' in my_string:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_string = "wolfofwalstreet(2012)is a movie"
if '(' in my_string:
    print('yes, "(" is in my_string')
```